# Complex Equation solving for another variable

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving, change-of-variable

I have been trying to re-arrange an equation to solve for another variable and I have not done algebra since college and am getting stuck in a rabbit hole. If anyone can help me figure this one out and showing me how you did it, I would really appreciate the refresher.

This current equation is solving for P but I want to re-arrange it to solve for i.

[Here is an image of the equation attached below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbMGP.png)

Comment: Most equations that you can write down do not have a solution that you can write down in an explicit formula. At school this usually not really tought and one concentrates only on those equations that do have explicit solutions, like e.g. quadratic equations. The problem with your equation is that the unknown ocurs once inside a (n+1)-power and once outside this power.  So, my guess is that is highly unlikely that the solution can be written down in an explicit formula... For concrete values for A, P and n, you can try to find a numerical solution using a computer but that is a different task.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).